# Improving codeigniter performance

Tags: mysql, performance, codeigniter

I am building a e commerce site like ebay.
I am using codeigniter. its too slow.
I've tried caching but still its too slow.
I know there is problem in my code. someone please suggest me how to improve load time or reduce query.

index function of home controller

```
public function index(){
        $this->load->model('homemodel');
        $data['menu'] = $this->homemodel->GetMenu();
        $data['slider'] = $this->homemodel->GetSlider();
        $data['popular'] = $this->homemodel->GetPopular();
        $data['new'] = $this->homemodel->GetNew();
        $data['featured'] = $this->homemodel->GetFeatured();
        $data['reviewed'] = $this->homemodel->GetMostReviewed();
        $data['seller'] = $this->homemodel->GetBestSeller();
        $data['auction'] = $this->homemodel->GetAuction();
        $data['deal'] = $this->homemodel->GetDeals();
        $this->load->view('index',$data);
    }
```

HOME MODEL

```
    public function GetMenu(){
        $this->db->select("*");
        $this->db->order_by("parentID");
        $query = $this->db->get("category");
        $result = $query->result_array();
        $p=0;$i=0;$cat="0";
        foreach($result as $items){
        //$cat.= $items['parentID']."<br>";
                if($items['parentID']==$p){
                        $menu[$p][$i] = $items;
                        $i++;
                }else{
                        $i=0;
                        $p=$items['parentID'];
                        $menu[$p][$i] = $items;
                        $i++;
                }
        }
        return $menu;
    }



    public function GetPopular(){
        $this->db->select("*");
        $this->db->where("parentID","0");
        $query = $this->db->get("category");
        $result = $query->result_array();
        $i=1;$pop='';
        foreach($result as $items){
            $this->db->select("*");
            $this->db->where("product.master_cat",$items['categoryID']);
            $this->db->where("product.popular","1");
            $this->db->where("images.ref_type","0");
            $this->db->where("images.is_cover","1");
            $this->db->join("images","images.ref_id=product.product_id");
            $query2 = $this->db->get("product");
            $pop[$i] = $query2->result_array();
            $i++;
        }
        return $pop;
    }



    public function GetNew($cid=NULL){
        if($cid!=''){
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM product JOIN `images` ON `images`.`ref_id`=`product`.`product_id` JOIN `product_reputation` ON `product_reputation`.`product_id`=`product`.`product_id` WHERE `product`.`category_id` IN (".$cid.") ORDER BY `product`.`product_id` DESC LIMIT 8");
    $res = $query->result_array();
    }else{
        $this->db->select("*");
        $this->db->order_by("product.product_id","DESC");
        $this->db->limit(8);
            $this->db->join("images","images.ref_id=product.product_id");
            $this->db->join("product_reputation","product_reputation.product_id=product.product_id");
            $query = $this->db->get("product");
            $res = $query->result_array();
        }
        return $res;
    }

    public function GetFeatured($cid=''){
        if($cid!=''){
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM product JOIN `images` ON `images`.`ref_id`=`product`.`product_id` JOIN `product_reputation` ON `product_reputation`.`product_id`=`product`.`product_id` WHERE product.is_featured='1' and `product`.`category_id` IN (".$cid.") ORDER BY `product`.`product_id` DESC LIMIT 8");
    $res = $query->result_array();
    }else{
    $this->db->select("*");
    $this->db->where("product.is_featured","1");
    $this->db->order_by("product.product_id","DESC");
    $this->db->limit(8);
        $this->db->join("images","images.ref_id=product.product_id");
        $this->db->join("product_reputation","product_reputation.product_id=product.product_id");
        $query = $this->db->get("product");
        $res = $query->result_array();
        }
        return $res;
    }

    public function GetMostReviewed($cid=''){
        if($cid!=''){
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM product JOIN `images` ON `images`.`ref_id`=`product`.`product_id` JOIN `product_reputation` ON `product_reputation`.`product_id`=`product`.`product_id` WHERE product.is_featured='1' and `product`.`category_id` IN (".$cid.") ORDER BY product_reputation.total_review DESC LIMIT 8");
    $res = $query->result_array();
    }else{
    $this->db->select("*");
    $this->db->where("product.is_featured","1");
    $this->db->order_by("product_reputation.total_review","DESC");
    $this->db->limit(8);
        $this->db->join("images","images.ref_id=product.product_id");
        $this->db->join("product_reputation","product_reputation.product_id=product.product_id");
        $query = $this->db->get("product");
        $res = $query->result_array();
        }
        return $res;
    }

    public function GetBestSeller($cid=''){
        if($cid!=''){
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM product JOIN `images` ON `images`.`ref_id`=`product`.`product_id` JOIN `seller_reputation` ON seller_reputation.seller_id=product.product_owner WHERE product.is_featured='1' and `product`.`category_id` IN (".$cid.") ORDER BY seller_reputation.total_review DESC LIMIT 8");
    $res = $query->result_array();
    }else{
    $this->db->select("*");
    $this->db->where("product.is_featured","1");
    $this->db->order_by("seller_reputation.total_review","DESC");
    $this->db->limit(8);
        $this->db->join("images","images.ref_id=product.product_id");
        $this->db->join("seller_reputation","seller_reputation.seller_id=product.product_owner");
        $query = $this->db->get("product");
        $res = $query->result_array();
        }
        return $res;
    }
```

These are sample methods. please provide some suggestion on that.

Thanks.

Comment: codeigniter caching completely bypasses the database so if you have really tried caching and its too slow then its an issue with your web server not your model methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are so many things that could be causing poor performance.  How many records are there in your database tables and are they properly indexed.  The SELECT * will have a performance overhead as the database query manager has to go to the metadata to find out which columns should be returned by the query.  If you specify the columns directly you will save some time.

Your GetPopular() function is getting a list of master records and then running a sub-query for each record in the master list.  This could be very slow depending on the number of records in the master list.  You would get better performance if you got the category and popular products in a single query (use a LEFT JOIN to avoid dropping categories with no popular products). If a category has more than one popular product, you will need to devise a method of getting distinct categories: This may simply be a separate query or it may be faster to iterate through the available category/product array

You may be autoloading a whole bunch of stuff that you don't need on this screen. Don't set all helpers and libraries to autoload.

But probably the biggest bottleneck will be the performance of the database and web servers.  Typically,if you are on a shared hosting plan the web server and database servers are separate (virtual) machines and there may be a significant network lag between the two, plus you will only have a limited amount of RAM and CPU cycles to play with.  If hosting speed is the issue then you will need to invest in a VPS at a minimum and possibly move your database away from MySQL to something with more grunt.  For a VPS and either MSSQL or Azure as a database you are probably looking at a couple of hundred dollars a month in hosting fees.